# nlog configuration - Time-based file archival doesnt work

Tags: iis, nlog

I have followed the example [here](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/File_target#Time-based_file_archival) and defined a Time-based file archives in my IIS as follows

```
<nlog autoReload="true" throwExceptions="true" >
 <targets async="true">
  <target name="file" type="File"
        layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}"
        fileName="${basedir}/logs/logfile.txt"
        archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/archives/log.{#}.${longdate}.txt"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        archiveNumbering="Rolling"
        maxArchiveFiles="31"
        concurrentWrites="true"
        keepFileOpen="false"
        encoding="iso-8859-2" />
 </targets>
<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
</rules>
```

although I have created the folders - files are not archived. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if you change the filetarget to log to a single file?  Have you tried troubleshooting the logging like described https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following config in all my projects and seems to archive just fine:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true">

    <variable name="LogFileName" value="App"/>
    <variable name="LogFileExtension" value="log"/>
    <variable name="LogsLocation" value="c:\TempFiles\AppLogs" />

    <targets async="true">
      <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" />
      <target name="flatFileTarget" xsi:type="File"
              layout="${date:format=dd-MM-yyyy HH\:mm\:ss.fff} | ${message}"
              fileName="${LogsLocation}\${LogFileName}.${LogFileExtension}"
              archiveFileName="${LogsLocation}\${LogFileName}.{#####}.${LogFileExtension}"
              archiveAboveSize="500000" maxArchiveFiles="10"
              archiveNumbering="Rolling"
              createDirs="true"
              concurrentWrites="true"
              archiveEvery="Day"
              deleteOldFileOnStartup="true" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
      <logger name="*" writeTo="flatFileTarget" />
      <logger name="*" writeTo="console" />
    </rules>

  </nlog>
```

Also make sure the user running the application has OS level write permissions to the folder where the logs files would be created. HTH.